# Ag Grid React re - renders per every 100 records while scrolling down

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I am trying to implement server side rendering based on page number & page size in Ag grid React. The page number & page size are dynamic and passed as arguments to the api. When the pageSize is 50 & 100, the ag grid works perfectly when i scroll down to see the data.  But the problem is that when the pageSize is 300 & 500, while i try to scroll down to see all the 300 records, after every 100 records the ag grid refreshes and dispatches the api. How can i avoid this re rendering after every 100 records and should be able to see all 300 records in the 1st page by scrolling down?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import { TextField, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';

const QuotationList = (props) => {

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const [pageSize, setPageSize] = React.useState(50);
const [gridApi, setGridApi] = React.useState(null);
const sizeList = ['50', '100', '300', '500'];

const onGridReady = (params) => {
setGridApi(params.api);
};

React.useEffect(() => {
if (gridApi) {
  const dataSource = {
    getRows: (params) => {
      const page = gridApi?.paginationProxy?.currentPage + 1;

      gridApi.showLoadingOverlay();

      const sorting = params.sortModel.map((sort) => ({
        colId: sort.colId,
        sort: sort.sort,
      }));

      const filtering = Object.keys(params.filterModel).map((colId) => ({
        colId: colId,
        filter: params.filterModel[colId].filter,
      }));
      dispatch(getAllQuotation(page, pageSize, sorting, filtering))
        .then((res) => {
          if (!res.data.content.length) {
            gridApi.showNoRowsOverlay();
          } else {
            gridApi.hideOverlay();
          }
          params.successCallback(res.data.content, res.data.totalElements);
        })
        .catch((err) => params.successCallback([], 0));
    },
  };

  gridApi.setDatasource(dataSource);
}
}, [gridApi, pageSize]);

return (
           <TextField
            label="Page size"
            variant="outlined"
            placeholder="Status"
            size="small"
            value={pageSize}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setPageSize(e.target.value);
            }}
            select
           >
            {sizeList.map((name) => (
              <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
                {name}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </TextField>

   <AgGridReact
        pagination={true}
        paginationPageSize={pageSize}
        rowModelType={'infinite'}   
        cacheBlockSize={pageSize}
        className="ag-theme-balham"
        rowStyle={rowStyle}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        tooltipShowDelay={500}
        onGridReady={onGridReady}
        enableCellTextSelection={true}
        onCellDoubleClicked={handleCellDoubleClick}
      ></AgGridReact>
)
}
```

This is the getAllQuotation function which is dispatched:

```
export const getAllQuotation = (page, size, sorting, filtering) => async (dispatch) => {

const queryParams = {
page,
size,
filter: JSON.stringify(filtering),
sort: JSON.stringify(sorting),
};

try {
dispatch({ type: GET_FFADMIN_QUOTATIONS_REQ });

const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
  },
};
const response = await jwtAxios.get('/ffadmin/quotations-list', {
  ...config,
  params: queryParams,
});
if (response.status === 200) {
  dispatch({
    type: GET_FFADMIN_QUOTATIONS_SUCCESS,
    payload: { ...response.data },
  });
  return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
    resolve(response);
  });
}
} catch (error) {
console.log(error.message);
dispatch({ type: GET_FFADMIN_QUOTATIONS_FAIL });
toast.error('Something went wrong!');
}
}; 

This is the package versions:

Package.json:

"ag-grid-react": "^26.1.0",
"react": "16.14.0",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
```

I tried changing cacheBlockSize prop but couldn't solve the issue. I want to scroll down and see all the 300 & 500 records without dispatching the api after every 100 records.